# From Python, to Java, Split ArrayList using Set()

Tags: java, python, set

This is the code in Python I'm trying to convert to Java:

```
self.active = set(self.genes[-self.output_length:]):
```

Reading up on the sets in Python, I believe that this is splitting the ArrayList at the index of 'self.output_length'. Is this correct? *A little background:* the 'self.genes' contains genes which present both 'self.output_length' and 'self.nodes'.

Could I used this in Java:

```
List<float[]> temp = this.genes.subList(0,this.output_length);
this.active = Set(Collections.reverse(temp));
```

UPDATE: As per a previous answer, I've now done this:

```
List<float[]> temp = this.genes.subList(this.genes.size() - this.output_length, this.genes.size()); 
this.active = new ArrayList<float[]> (temp);
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Could anyone point me to some documentation on the [-n:]? I've tried to look under http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html, but can't figure it out. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use an ordered set in Java, use one of implementations of [SortedSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html). You need not to reverse the order of List before filling the Set, as it has no effect. To provide required ordering, pass a Comparator to the Set's implementation constructor.